# Can't inject album art into WAV file using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I know it's possible to inject album art into a WAV file, because there are various applications that do this (like Metadatics on the Mac).

When I try to do this with FFmpeg, though, it doesn't work:

`cat original.wav | ffmpeg -y -i pipe:0 -i albumart.jpg -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c copy -write_id3v2 1 with-artwork.wav`

This results in the following error:

```
[wav @ 0x7fa044037200] WAVE files have exactly one stream
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

What parameters do I need to use to get this working? If it won't do it, is there another *nix-based tool that will work?

Comment: I‘m not sure the .wav container _can_ have album artwork metadata injected. As a test, you could try first converting the wav to a few other audio container formats and try to apply the above operation to them

Comment: I was able to embed album art into a plain WAV file using Metadatics: https://www.markvapps.com/metadatics

Comment: In which case your best bet is asking over at super user. This down to the behaviour of FFMPEG and not a programming problem. Meta data in wav is not part of the standard header. It is possible that FFMPEG have chosen not to implement this or that it requires extra steps https://superuser.com/

Comment: Got a solution: https://taglib.org. But since it's just a library, I need someone to build an executable around this.